# How exactly works this Angular 2 custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives, angular-directive, javascript-framework

I am very new in **Angular 2** and I am following a tutorial about how to create a custom directive and I have some doubts about how it exactly works.

I will try to explain what it was done.

I have a view containing something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div
      class="btn-group"
      appDropDown
     >
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">Manage Recipe <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">To Shopping List</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Edit Recipe</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Delete Recipe</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see this dive having class **btn-group** have my custom **appDropDown** setted on

```
<div
    class="btn-group"
    appDropDown
>
```

This custom directive simply add the **open** class to this div when the inner button is clicked (so the UL content is showed by BootStrap).

This is the code of my custom directive:

```
import {Directive, HostBinding, HostListener} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropDown]'
})
export class DropDownDirective {

  @HostBinding('class.open') isOpen = false;

  // listen to a click event:
  @HostListener('click') toggleOpen() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }

}
```

From what I can undestood this directive works in this way:

1) This line:

```
@HostBinding('class.open') isOpen = false;
```

bound the **isOpen** variable to the value of the **class.open** attribute of the div on which my custom directive is applied.

So it should mean that if this dive have the **open** class setted the value will be true, otherwise will be false.

Is it this interpretation correct?

2) This method:

```
// listen to a click event:
@HostListener('click') toggleOpen() {
  this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
}
```

is performed when the user click this button in the view:

```
  <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">Manage Recipe <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
```

Ok, now my doubt is: why this methis is performed only when I click this specific button and not when any other button in my page is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So it should mean that if this dive have the open class setted the
>   value will be true, otherwise will be false.

It's actually the other way round. If the property `isOpen` is true the class `open` will be added to the div. If false - removed.

> is performed when the user click this button in the view:

Actually, it will be triggered when there is a click on any element that is the child of the element to which you apply a directive because native events bubble.

If you want to check for the `button` specifically, use the following code:

```
  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
  clicked(element) {
    if (element.classList.contains('dropdown-toggle')) {
      console.log('button clicked');
    }
  }
```